# Why node.js does not accept filename "node.js"

Tags: node.js

I'm starting to learn node.js.
To check if installation works I created a file named "node.js" (created it quickly on desktop and named it like that just to know it's for node).

When I run `node node.js` - file runs with Microsoft JScript but when I change name to i.e. "a.js" and run `node a.js` it runs with node.

Just wondering why node does not runs such a file with this name? Is there a list of forbidden names?

Comment: I guess it is nothing to do with the name of the file, I just tried it runs perfectly fine. The issue might be the location file is present(assuming that there might be a system file which hinders with the name node) try it changing the location.

Comment: why it may be location if another name works? moved to c:\ and still does not work - still runs with a Microsoft JSrcipt

Comment: Can't reproduce either on linux! It is working fine for `node node.js`

Comment: when I run `node node.js` there is thrown window exception from Microsoft JScript that console is unknown (js file contains only console.log()), so it runs the same as command `node.js`

Comment: I can even run `node node node node node node.js` etc, and the result is the same, `node` is ignored(?)